# Running a saved trained model on multiple images

Tags: deep-learning

I have a deep learning CNN classifier in tensorflow which I have trained and saved to disk.

At the moment, I'm only running the model on one image at a time. However, I would like to automate this to classify a batch of 100s if not 1,000s of images.

Is there a way to do this and record the output? Below is my current code block for achieving this.

Much appreciated.

```
# since we are using Jupyter Notebooks we can replace our argument
# parsing code with *hard coded* arguments and values
args = {
    "model": "pokedex.model",
    "labelbin": "lb.pickle",
    "image": "examples/Roxy.jpg"
}

# load the image
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
output = image.copy()

# pre-process the image for classification
image = cv2.resize(image, (96, 96))
image = image.astype("float") / 255.0
image = img_to_array(image)
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

# load the trained convolutional neural network and the label
# binarizer
print("[INFO] loading network...")
model = load_model(args["model"])
lb = pickle.loads(open(args["labelbin"], "rb").read())

# classify the input image
print("[INFO] classifying image...")
proba = model.predict(image)[0]
idx = np.argmax(proba)
label = lb.classes_[idx]

# we'll mark our prediction as "correct" of the input image filename
# contains the predicted label text (obviously this makes the
# assumption that you have named your testing image files this way)
filename = args["image"][args["image"].rfind(os.path.sep) + 1:]
correct = "correct" if filename.rfind(label) != -1 else "none_detected"

# build the label and draw the label on the image
label = "{}: {:.2f}% ({})".format(label, proba[idx] * 100, correct)
output = imutils.resize(output, width=400)
cv2.putText(output, label, (10, 25),  cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
    0.7, (0, 255, 0), 2)

# show the output image
print("[INFO] {}".format(label))
plt_imshow("Output", output)
```

Comment: Please give full information. Is it in TensorFlow? Is it in Sklearn? Pytorch?

Comment: Thanks, updated with more information.